# Define a property in Typescript to prevent compilation error in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export class ListService {
    ...
    getAllLists(): Observable<List[]> {
        let URI = `${this.serverApi}/bucketlist/`;
        return this.http.get<List[]>(URI)
            .pipe(
                map(res => <List[]>res.lists)
            );
    } 
}
```

When compile with `ng serve`, it displays following error

`error TS2339: Property 'lists' does not exist on type 'List[]'.`

It is known that `res.lists` is `List[]` type. What is the better way for defining the property for `res` so that the code will compile without error?

This is a `res` sample

```
{
  "success": true,
  "lists": [
    {
      "_id": "5c6673abeb64adb41ec6dfaf",
      "title": "First Project"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Solution Attempted

```
interface Response {
    success: boolean;
    lists: List[];
}
export class ListService { 
    getAllLists(): Observable<List[]> {
        ...
        return this.http.get<Response>(URI)
            .pipe(
                map(res => res.lists)
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try adding parantheses like this `<List[]>(res.lists)` or `map(res => res.lists as List[])`

Comment: @Korfoo both method does not work, still seeing error when compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

`res` looks like an object, not like a `List[]`. So `http.get<List[]>` won't work.

## Try this

```
interface MyResponse {
  success: boolean;
  lists: List[];
}

export class ListService {
    ...
    getAllLists(): Observable<List[]> {
        let URI = `${this.serverApi}/bucketlist/`;

        // Replace 'List[]' with 'MyResponse' here
        return this.http.get<MyResponse>(URI)
            .pipe(
                map(res => res.lists)
            );
    } 
}
```

## Explanation

When you write `this.http.get<List[]>(URI)` your compiler is expecting a response of type **Array of `List`**. The problem is that the response does not match the signature. As you said `res` look more like

```
{
  "success": true,
  "lists": [
    {
      "_id": "5c6673abeb64adb41ec6dfaf",
      "title": "First Project"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see that it's not an array so the `List[]` won't work

Comment: Casting to a new interface is a good idea! Should I do `map(res => (<Response>res).lists)`? This still doesn't work

Comment: You need to include `MyResponse` into `this.http.get`. Like this `this.http.get<MyReponse>`. Look at the first snippet after my last edit

Comment: You forgot the __`this.http.get<Response>(URI)`__ part. __That is the bug__ @ClintonLam

Answer (score 1):

I think syntax would be -

```
  map((res: <List[]>) => res.lists)
```

Or even you can omit to typecast response at the time of map, when you already did it here `this.http.get<List[]>...`

Comment: I need typecast the response for better bug-proof the code

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is casting `res` to the `List[]` so to cast the `res.lists` put parenthesis as suggested by @Korfoo.